# How do I dereference the return value of a function returning a pointer without using a temporary variable?

Tags: c++, qt

C++ noob here.

So, this is a member function of my `class DbHelper`:

```
QSqlQueryModel* getCourses();
```

Now, whenever I do this in `class MyModel` where `QSqlQueryModel courses` is a member:

```
this->courses = *(dbHelper->getCourses()); // problem here ... this is inside a member function of MyModel
```

Visual Studio says that

> function ... operator= cannot be referenced ... it is a deleted
>   function

Of course I can do this instead:

```
QSqlQueryModel* q = dbHelper->getCourses();
this->courses = *q;
```

But I'm thinking that declaring another variable just to dereference it is possibly redundant. So is there a shorter way?

**EDIT:**

Just verified it with VS and it turned out I really can't. My mind really just got messed up in studying pointers and references the entire afternoon. Thanks people.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux QSqlQueryModel courses;

Comment: Please show the complete error message. It would be helpful to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: `this->courses = *(dbHelper->getCourses()); ` and `QSqlQueryModel* q = dbHelper->getCourses(); this->courses = *q;` should be doing the exact same thing.  Can we get a [mcve]?

Comment: "Of course I can do this instead:" no you cannot for the same reason

Comment: Oh. Just verified it with VS and it turned out I really can't. My mind really just got messed up in studying pointers and references the entire afternoon. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authors of the `QSqlQueryModel` class are being cute and are cleverly forbidding the copying of instances of that object.

The class member should be a pointer type:

```
QSqlQueryModel* courses;
```

as the documentation states that you don't own the memory associated with the pointer. Then you set trivially

```
this->courses = dbHelper->getCourses();
```

Comment: The question states that `this->courses = *q;` works.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Which, with respect to the OP, is a figment of their imagination. (And the OP has just confirmed that in a comment.)

Comment: Then the question should be closed for not being reproducible.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: This is one of those instances where if the question were perfect then the answer would already be known to the OP. It's not the crux of the question, and can stay open in my opinion.

Comment: @Bathsheba. Thanks. But may I ask how did you know that? That is, how do I know if instances of a class cannot be copied? Are there keywords involved or is it found only in the docs (I read it but found nothing)? Thanks again.

Comment: @SidGo: If you want to "go to source", you could search for something like `QSqlQueryModel operator=(const QSqlQueryModel&)  = delete;`. That is the canonical way of deleting the assignment operator. C++11 onwards. And the compiler error you cite spells it out nicely. You'll find that the copy constructor is deleted too. We call this the "noncopyable idiom", and we used to achieve it by making the methods `private`, and not supplying an implementation.

Comment: That's what VS means when it says "it is a deleted function"